# How to count consonants in a string without using brute force method

Tags: python, count

I did it with the brute force method. I'd like to know to count this string without using brute method.

```
def countConsonat (s):
    count = 0
    for c in s:
        if c in ("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"):
            count +=1
    return count
print (countConsonant ('"Carpe diem", every day.'))
```

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with that. The only thing I would suggest here is you can do a slight simplification where you can do `if c.lower() in ()` where what is in the parentheses are the lower case letters of the consonants.

Comment: Another way is to use regular expressions and get an string with the vowels and get it's length